# How can I compare 2 large objects running on separate jvm's?

Tags: java

I am looking at changing the way some large objects which maintain the data for a large website are reloaded, they contain data relating to catalogue structure, products etc and get reloaded daily.

After changing how they are reloaded I need to be able to see whether there is any difference in the resulting data so the intention is to reload both and compare the content.

There may be some issues(ie. lists used when ordering is not imporatant) that make the comparison harder so I would need to be able to alter the structure before comparison. I have tried to serialise to json using gson but I run out of memory. I'm thinking of trying other serialisation methods or writing my own simple one.

I imagine this is something that other people will have wanted to do when changing critical things like this but I haven't managed to find anythign about it.

Comment: Why not just versionning your data? i.e. keeping a separate file that contains a version number which is incremented at every modification.

Comment: @gma I need to be able to generate this file from the object in a way that is comparable between versions. This means it can't have any arbitrary meta-data such as the references in the java serialisation output. Also, Sets would need to be compared without ordering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this special case (separate VMs) I suggest adding something like a `dump` method to each class which writes the relevant content into a file (human readable text). This method calls `dump` on each aggregated object as well.

In the end you have to files from each VM, and then you can compare them using an MD5 checksum for example.

This is probably a lot of work, but if you encounter any differences, you can use `diff` on both files, and this will be a great help.

You can start with a simple version, and refine it step-by-step by adding more output.

Adding (complete) serialization later to a class is cumbersome. There might be tools which simplify this (using reflection etc.), but in my experience you have to tweak your classes: Exclude fields which are not relevant, define a sort order for lists, cyclic relations etc.

Actually I use a similar approach for the same reasons (to check whether a new version still returns the same result): The application contains multiple services (for each version), the results are always *data transfer objects*, serialization is added immediately to the DTOs, and DTOs must provide a comparison method dedicated for this purpose.

Comment: I might be wrong, but isnt this what they call Serialization? Just like you are saying in the last paragraph.

Comment: @Terence There is a difference: Serialization covers all data (in terms of `equal`), but in case of a result comparison, you are normally interested in only a subset of fields. For example, meta data like *executed on host x in xxx milliseonds* is serialized, but not compared.

Comment: I was mainly interested in whether I could do it without writing my own serialisation for all the classes involved, whether some general serialisation would be effective, but it seems like everyone is suggesting the same thing.

Comment: @MikeB Sorry for the bad news :-) It's based on my experience: Adding generic serialization later tends to be frustrating, adding a self-made/tailored "partial serialization" is tedious - but more "deterministic". And if you manage to serialize (and de-serialize!) completely: It could be hard to spot the problem, if `equals` returns false.

Comment: @Beryllium Yes, it still looks like it's too much work at the moment - also since this is a regression test I'd like to not have to touch all those classes too much

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the complications and memory issues, also as you have mentioned you dont want to maintain versions, i would look to use database for comparison.
It will need some effort in terms of mapping your data in jvm to db table but once you have done that, it will be staright forward. You can dump data from one large object in db tables and then you can simply run a check from 2nd object in db.
Creating a stored proc can simplify things. This solution can support data check from any number of jvms.

Comment: I would be interested to use a database for comparison but only if there were a general way to map the object to it (the same as for the serialisation). I wouldn't be interested in mapping it into entity tables as the data in this object is already loaded from over 20 tables.